# update a value BEFORE running a function containing ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

On page load, the code below performs an api request and returns the result. I then have some code that on change of a selector updates one of the variables with the value of that selector and then re-requests the api using the function newsFeed();

My problem is the variable is not getting updated before the function has run.

How do you update a value before running a function containing ajax?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var api = '//www.url.com'
var search = 'search?'
var orderBy = 'newest'

var url = api + search + orderBy

//API Call Setup        
function newsFeed(data) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function results(data) {
            for (var i =0; i < data.response.total; i++) {
                var content = '<li>' + data.response.results[i] + '</li>';
                $('#news').append(content);     
            //end of for loop
            };                   
        }
    });       
}

newsFeed();

$("#selector").change(function(){      
   $('#news').empty(); //remove all child nodes  
    orderBy = $("#orderBy :selected").text();        
    newsFeed(); 
});
});
```

Comment: Remove the `newsFeed();` call that's on it's own just after the `newsFeed` function.  If you just want it to run when the dropdown changes then the rest is fine.

Comment: @Archer that call is in there as I want the code to run on page load

Comment: So what isn't happening then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the `orderBy` variable, but then not updating the `url` with that. Move the declaration of `url` so it's in the same block as the AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var api = '//www.url.com';
    var search = 'search?';
    var orderBy = 'newest';

    //API Call Setup        
    function newsFeed(data) {

        var url = api + search + orderBy; // This line has been moved

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function results(data) {
                for (var i =0; i < data.response.total; i++) {
                    var content = '<li>' + data.response.results[i] + '</li>';
                    $('#news').append(content);     
                };                   
            }
        });       
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax call, you are requesting `url: url`

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
```

With url defined as

```
var url = api + search + orderBy
```

But `var url` doesn't get magically updated by changing one of the composing variable's value. 
Once you've set `url` it's set (until you update it), so that would be the variable you'd need to update.

The quickest fix will be to just get rid of `var url` at all and use the ajax call like

```
$.ajax({
        url: api + search + orderBy,
```

Answer (score 0):

As baao said, your `url` variable inside `newsFeed()` doesn't get updated. I'd suggest passing variables as parameters to the `newsFeed` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var api = '//www.url.com'
  var search = 'search?'
  //API Call Setup        
  function newsFeed(orderBy) {
    // set url every time function is called
    var url = api + search + orderBy

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function results(data) {
          for (var i =0; i < data.response.total; i++) {
              var content = '<li>' + data.response.results[i] + '</li>';
              $('#news').append(content);     
          //end of for loop
          };                   
      }
    });       
  }

  // First call with default orderBy value
  newsFeed('newest');

  $("#selector").change(function(){      
     $('#news').empty(); //remove all child nodes  
      orderBy = $("#orderBy :selected").text();        
      newsFeed(orderBy); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to arrange your code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var api = '//www.url.com'
var search = 'search?'
var orderBy = 'newest'

var url = api + search + orderBy


$("#selector").change(function(){      
   $('#news').empty(); //remove all child nodes  
    orderBy = $("#orderBy :selected").text();        
    newsFeed(); 
});


//API Call Setup        
function newsFeed(data) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function results(data) {
            for (var i =0; i < data.response.total; i++) {
                var content = '<li>' + data.response.results[i] + '</li>';
                $('#news').append(content);     
            //end of for loop
            };                   
        }
    });       
}

    newsFeed(); 

});
```